# how do I edit the navigation menu in AngularJS theme?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

So, I bought a template from [envato market](http://market.envato.com/). It's an admin panel responsive theme created with bootstrap and AngularJS. I want to edit the theme. I've edited the navigation links in the `nav.html` file and also in the `config.router.js` file, where they were defined as `.state` blocks. But they are still not showing the names I want them to. 
Is there any other place where all these name are being declared?

And also, I want some more toggle buttons on the off-sidebar. I've added them but I don't know where to define their models and other things like IDs and classes.

Documentation doesn't provide any information about the files in which these menus are defined.
Here's the [link to the theme](http://themeforest.net/item/cliptwo-bootstrap-admin-template-with-angularjs/10290688).

Here's the `.state`s for the links in main navigation:

```js
$stateProvider.state('app', {
        url: "/app",
        templateUrl: "assets/views/app.html",
        resolve: loadSequence('modernizr', 'moment', 'uiSwitch', 'perfect-scrollbar-plugin', 'perfect_scrollbar', 'toaster', 'ngAside', 'vAccordion', 'sweet-alert', 'chartjs', 'tc.chartjs', 'oitozero.ngSweetAlert'),
        abstract: true
    }).state('app.dashboard', {
        url: "/dashboard",
        templateUrl: "assets/views/dashboard.html",
        resolve: loadSequence('jquery-sparkline', 'sparkline', 'dashboardCtrl'),
        title: 'Dashboard',
        ncyBreadcrumb: {
            label: 'Dashboard'
        }
    }).state('app.prospects', {
        url: '/prospects',
        template: '<div ui-view class="fade-in-up"></div>',
        title: 'Prospects',
        ncyBreadcrumb: {
            label: 'Prospects'
        }
    })
```

And this is relevant anchor tag in the `nav.html` file:

```html
<ul class="main-navigation-menu">
 <li ui-sref-active="active">
  <a ui-sref="app.dashboard">
   <div class="item-content">
    <div class="item-media">
     <i class="ti-home"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="item-inner">
     <span class="title" translate="sidebar.nav.dashboard.MAIN"> Dashboard </span>
    </div>
   </div>
  </a>
 </li>
    <div class="navbar-title">
        <span>PIPELINE</span>
    </div>
    <li ng-class="{'active open':$state.includes('app.prospects')}">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">
            <div class="item-content">
                <div class="item-media">
                    <i class="ti-folder"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="item-inner">
                    <span class="title" translate="sidebar.nav.tables.MAIN"> Prospects </span><i class="icon-arrow"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
```

Comment: Can you show us some code it's quite difficult to think without code.

Comment: Just edit your question.

Comment: added the snippets in the questions @squiroid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The side navigation items are being translated by angular-translate.  If your IDE's grep/search isn't picking them up it is probably because you haven't assiciated the .json file type with the program.

The translations for your nav items will be in something like: {layout}/{STANDARD}/assets/i18n/en.json

Edit this file and you will see your nav item's proper changes.